# sed or awk command to insert tabs (delimiter) at specific positions

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am trying to parse a table with variable number of delimiters to convert into a table of equal columns:

```
cluster=96\troot\tcellular organisms\tno_rank no_rank$

cluster=42\troot\tcellular organisms\tBacteria\tno_rank\tno_rank\tsuperkingdom$

cluster=362\troot\tcellular organisms\tBacteria\tProteobacteria\tno rank\tno rank\tsuperkingdom\tphylum$

cluster=12330\troot\tcellular organisms\tBacteria\tTerrabacteria\tFirmicutes\tClostridia\tClostridiales\tClostridiaceae\tClostridium\tno rank\tno rank\tsuperkingdom\tno rank\tphylum\tclass\torder\tfamily\tgenus$
```

The expected output is:

```
cluster=96\troot\tcellular organisms\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tno_rank\tno_rank\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$

cluster=42\troot\tcellular organisms\tBacteria\t\t\t\t\t\t\tno_rank\tno_rank\tsuperkingdom\t\t\t\t\t\t$

cluster=362\troot\tcellular organisms\tBacteria\tProteobacteria\t\t\t\t\t\tno rank\tno rank\tsuperkingdom\tphylum\t\t\t\t\t$

cluster=12330\troot\tcellular organisms\tBacteria\tTerrabacteria\tFirmicutes\tClostridia\tClostridiales\tClostridiaceae\tClostridium\tno rank\tno rank\tsuperkingdom\tno rank\tphylum\tclass\torder\tfamily\tgenus$
```

"\t" is tab delimiter and "$" is end of line

Comment: How would anyone know where to add the extra columns?  Do you know in advance how many columns you expect, or do you need to find the row with the most and then make everything match that?

Comment: Yes I want to add the columns with the max number of columns in the file

Comment: Is the conversion from underscores to spaces accidental?

Comment: sorry, there is not underscore

Comment: Your input still appears inconsistent (`no_rank` versus `no rank`). Also your title says "specific" but I don't see any actual specification - for example, how to decide how many of the additional tabs should go before the first `no_rank` and how many at the end? Are we supposed to count that or is there a maximum number of missing fields in each position (before and after `no_rank`)?

Comment: The columns starting from the first "no rank" till the "end of line" are the description of the taxa names starting from "root". Each line has exact descriptions of taxa name columns (Such as for "root" description is "no rank" and for  "Bacteria" description is "superkingdom").

Comment: for example in the first line there is 7 tabs (to fill the missing tabs for line 4) required at both places before first "no rank" and "end of line"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Awk with two passes:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==NR {if (NF>a) {a=NF}; next} NF<a{$a=""} 1' file file
```

This will add the extra tabs at the *end* of the lines with missing fields.

---

Based on your exact sample data, I think it is likely you are dealing with a problem impossible to solve programmatically.  If you need extra tabs in an intermediate position to ensure the `no_rank` values end up in the right column, you will need some fancier logic.

Comment: yes the tabs should be inserted before the first occurrence of "no rank" and end of the line

Comment: @user3472737, edit your *example text* in your question, then.  It doesn't match what you are saying.  You show some tabs being added at the end of the line and some in the middle.

Comment: Actually there is 18 columns at max which is mainly separated at middle with "no rank". so I want to add missing columns before first "no rank" and end of line

Comment: @user3472737 that information should be edited into your question

Comment: I edited the above example is it clear or need to some more additions

Comment: Columns starting from "no rank"are the descriptions of the columns start with "root"

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller): I answered a similar question [for CSV here](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/cookbook.html#Regularizing_ragged_CSV) but in that case the max length was already available in the header line so there was no need to search for it elsewhere.

In this case, where the max length may be elsewhere, the best I could do was:

```
cat in.dat | mlr --nidx --fs tab --nidx put -q '
  @maxnf = max(@maxnf, NF);
  @records[NR] = $*; # Retain
  @counts[NR] = NF;

  end {
    for (i in @records) {
      @record = @records[i];
      for (j = @counts[i] + 1; j <= @maxnf; j += 1) { # add extra fields
        @record["x".j] = "";
      }
      emit @record;            # insert into the output record stream
    }
  }
'
```

Idea is to retain the record-list and max NF; then process in an end-block. Note that this uses features in head (not in the latest 4.5.0 release).